# Virtual camera/direct show filter for network stream

Tags: c#, stream, virtual, camera, directshow

i'm working with Flash Live Encoder.
It's using camera for streaming video.
Support forum say's that i can create custom direct show filter and stream data that i need.
I cann't understand how direct show filter will display in the source list of the live encoder.
I've tryed to use some commercial virtual camera and it work's fine, but it cann't use source from network stream.

Summary. I have a several network streams. I think that i must to create virtual camera for each one. But if i find examples with direct show filter on C#, i cann't find for virtual camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example here of how to do a virtual capture device.  You will have to use C++ to implement it.  You will also have to implement the code to get the network stream and parse it into samples for DirectShow to understand.

> Capture Source Filter filter (version
>   0.1) 86 KB zipped, includes binaries.  A sample source filter that emulates a
>   video capture device contributed...video capture device contributed...

http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads.htm