# create virtual webcam application which takes images as input and send it to any video chat application

Tags: visual-studio, directshow, winapi

In my project i'm getting live camera images from remote bluetooth device. and now i want these images to show on any video chat application like facebook, skype etc.

Means i want the application which pretend as webcam and take the images as input and send it t chat window.

I heard about **DirectShow** filters. but as i'm new to this i need whole step-by-step procedure to develop above application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Virtual camera/direct show filter for network stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882792/virtual-camera-direct-show-filter-for-network-stream)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anthology of the question:

- [Virtual camera/direct show filter for network stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882792/virtual-camera-direct-show-filter-for-network-stream)
- [Virtual webcam input as byte stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557723/virtual-webcam-input-as-byte-stream)
- [Custom virtual video capture device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569238/custom-virtual-video-capture-device)

Comment: I know that my question is duplicate of one you mentioned but i'm not yet found the specific method. I've implemented virtual camera source filter http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads.htm . i've created dll and registered it with regsvr32 after that what i should do.

Comment: As soon as you register the DLL, you see a new video device in GraphEdit Windows SDK tool, AmCap Windows SDK sample, Skype and other DriectShow-enabled applications.

Comment: Thnx. i got it in AmCap's video device category. now when i say preview it doesn't show any preview as i haven't given any input. tell me how give the input. i have jpeg images coming through remote bluetooth device and i want to preview them as video.

Comment: You are supposed to do it, to implement it within the project you used as a base.

Comment: StackOverflow and MSDN forums have a number of discussions on this topic. Your particular requests was discussed far more than once. Start researching older topics and you will find the way.

Comment: sir, where should i implement my bluetooth module for getting images from remote device and from where to feed these images to my source filter. can you please give me your email address. my email id:ashishgabhane1@gmail.com