# How can I take a VLC stream and turn it into a usable Windows "video source"?

Tags: windows, stream, directshow, vlc

Essentially I'm trying to use VLC to stream an existing video source over a local network to another computer. I'm trying to find a way to create a video source out of that network stream so I can use it in different applications.

So to visualize:

```
comp1 video source --> vlc --> network stream --> unknown program on comp2 --> new video source --> any program of my choosing on comp2
```

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You expose a video feed to applications via virtual DirectShow camera/device. There is a number of questions already asked and answered on this:

- [Virtual webcam input as byte stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557723/virtual-webcam-input-as-byte-stream/8557841#8557841)
- [Virtual camera/direct show filter for network stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882792/virtual-camera-direct-show-filter-for-network-stream/2926838#2926838)
- [How to use directshow filter as a live input for Expression Encoder 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870843/how-to-use-directshow-filter-as-a-live-input-for-expression-encoder-4/7871719#7871719)
- [create virtual webcam application which takes images as input and send it to any video chat application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971329/create-virtual-webcam-application-which-takes-images-as-input-and-send-it-to-any/9974058#9974058)

VLC alone is not capable to register itself as a virtual camera.